"She will be confused by talking too much"
Active "I will confuse her by talking too much". Passive "She will be confused by me by talking too much" (I know, Its me who is talking)
But If I do not mention the agent and simply say,
"She will be confused by talking too much"
Then who is talking? Is it me or her? I think it could be anyone but more grammatically its "Me" who is talking because in passive being an object i am performing the action and "She" being a subject is on receiving end.

(1) Active "I will confuse her by talking too much". (2) Passive She will be confused by me talking too much. If you simply say, "She will be confused by talking too much", then you mean that she will be confused because she is talking.

It sort of sounds like you think that women are (1) stupid and (2) the passive recipients of things that men do. I hope that isn't so?

@MichaelHarvey im afraid no, not at all. I never meant to say that.I was asking a question interms of grammar and not interms of any other thing.

@MichaelHarvey "The room will be ready/completed by painting the walls". Here do you not think that "by painting the walls" refers to an agent/painter who will do the painting because the room itself cannot do the painting?

@MichaelHarvey "The fire system wil be turned on by pressing the button". Kindly correct me if I am wrong that "By pressing the button" refers to  an agent/person who is pressing button because fire sytem itself cannot press the button

Pressing is a different type of verb from talking.

First get the basics right. future subject + will + Infinitive i) I will confuse her ii) You will confuse her iii) He will confuse her etc. PASSIVE sub + will + be + past participle : She will be confused by me/you/him etc.

@Mari-LouA My mistake.actually it was a typo but thanks for correction. I correct it now.

Too much talking will confuse her  is how I might phrase it. Who is doing the excessive talking? Without context we cannot possibly know for certain. WE need to know what was said earlier. Is there a reason why this sentence must be passivized?

“She will be confused by MY/  YOUR/ HIS  talking too much” see ELU When is a 'gerund' supposed to be preceded by a possessive adjective/determiner?

@Mari-LouA Actually i have often heard by+ing sentences in active voice so i thought of it in passive voice but then by+ing in passive voice made me confused as in who is performing an action whether it is subject or object

to be confused by something is not to confuse a person or confuse A with B

I rephrase a bit.

The person will be confused by talking too much.

will be interpreted grammatically
as he or she doing the talking .  This is not very likely as a person's talking shouldn't confuse himself or herself; it is more likely to confuse others.  (However, this is possible: He or she will be seen as confused by talking too much.)
Hence the talking is likely by another person, and we should state that (you, me, him, her, us or them).  In formal writing, we use the possessive pronoun:
The person will be confused by my talking too much.
Here the agent is my talking too much.
When we use the less formal object case
He or she will be confused by me talking too much
the agent is me.

thanks.Considering your explanation, Can I also say" Room will be completed by my painting the waĺls" " Alarm will be activated by my pressing the button"?

@Bilal Zafar, The room will be completed by my painting the walls and The alarm will be activated by my pressing the button are grammatical but less likely than The room will be completed after I've painted the walls and The alarm will be activated if I press the button.
